# How to list all stripe charges for a particular customer using curl

Tags: curl, stripe-payments

I'm using curl and the stripe api to list charges

curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges -u sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:

This returns all the charges but I'd like to only list charges for a particular customer id without returning everything and then having to filter the response.

Thanks

Comment: In the docs it says 
customer optional

Only return charges for the customer specified by this customer ID but I cant find the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges?customer=cus_XXXXXXXXXX -u sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
```

API Documentation:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_charges-customer